# Using set instead of list in Django and checking the id with each id in the list

Tags: python, django

```
def user(request):
  users_list = UserConfig.objects.get(meta_key="ALLOWED_USERS")
  users_list = [int(x) for x in user_list.meta_value.split(",")]
  if request.user.id not in users_list:
   // some logic
  else: 
    // other logic
```

How can I convert the above snippet by using of a set, currently I am using list to check. So if the Object gets more then it won't be a efficient way.

Using Django 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i convert the above snippet by using of a set

well, technically you could just do this:

```
users_set = set(int(x) for x in user_list.meta_value.split(","))
```

BUT your real issue here is a design issue - you should NOT store a list of related pks (you should not store any list of any kind FWIW) in one single field. Either use existing `auth.User` features, or use permissions, or use a custom User model and add your own things to it etc, but by all means keep your relational schema properly normalized. My 2 cents...

Comment: so i can use if request.user.id not in user_lists isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `set` from the list.

```
users_list = UserConfig.objects.get(meta_key="ALLOWED_USERS")
users_list = [int(x) for x in user_list.meta_value.split(",")]
users_list = set(users_list)
```

You can also use Set comprehension.

```py
users_list = {int(x) for x in user_list.meta_value.split(",")}
```

Comment: `Queryset.get()` returns one single model instance, not a queryset, so this 1/ useless (you won't have "duplicate rows" with a `.get()` call), and 2/ broken - it will try to call `distinct()` on your model instance (and this is definitly not an existing default model method), not on a queryset.

Comment: thanks @brunodesthuilliers for pointing out the error, I completely missed that `get()` in the question.

Answer (score 1):

While it’s true that sets have a much quicker lookup time compared to lists, they don’t preserve the order of the data. So just be aware of that when deciding which data structure to use.

```
def user(request):
    users_list = UserConfig.objects.get(meta_key="ALLOWED_USERS")
    users_list = [int(x) for x in user_list.meta_value.split(",")]
    user_set = set(users_list)
    if request.user.id not in users_set:
        // some logic
    else: 
        // other logic
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but if you must use that model as is and you want a faster lookup, I think you can use a dynamic regex pattern to find if the user id is in that list:

```py
import re
def user(request):
    users_list = UserConfig.objects.get(meta_key="ALLOWED_USERS")
    pattern = "{0},".format(request.user.id)
    if re.search(pattern, users_list):
        # User is in list
    else:
        # User not in list
```

This is just an idea and assumes that your string has every id followed by a comma, including the last one.

Comment: On py3.6.9, this is indeed about one order of magnitude faster... But it's still not the proper way to use a RDBMS.